# Saving data from NonlinearModelFit

Tags: export, fitting, save

If you use  NonlinearModelFit the results are put into some sort of output package. How do you save these packages so that you can go back to them later? My particular problem is that I generating hundreds of packages.
Here is a toy example with just two

```
ClearAll[a1, a2, res];
data1 = Table[{x, (x + 3)/(x + 2) + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {x, 0,5, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[{x, (x + 3)/(x + 2) + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {x, 0,5, 0.1}];
res1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, (x + a1)/(x + a2), {a1, a2}, x];
res2 = NonlinearModelFit[data2, (x + a1)/(x + a2), {a1, a2}, x];
```

The results has all sorts of good information stored within it, for example

```
res2["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I wish to save all this information for analysis on another day so I write

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Save["test.s", {res1, res2}]
```

When I try and get the data back this is what I get

```
oldfits = Get["test.s"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is just the last example. I guess one solution would be to store each package individually, however this would be a flood of files. I have also tried text files but this does not help. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exporting the NonlinearModelFit result objects as mx seems to work fine.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
ClearAll[dat0, nmf0, pcit0];
dat0 = Table[{x, (x + 3)/(x + 2) + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {iSet, 
1, 10, 1}, {x, 0, 5, 0.01}];
Dimensions@dat0

nmf0 = Table[NonlinearModelFit[dat0[[iSet]], (x + a1)/(x + a2), {a1, a2},x], {iSet, Length@dat0}];


pcit0 = Table[nmf0[[iSet]]["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"], {iSet,Length@nmf0}]


Export["nmf0.mx", nmf0]
ClearAll[nmf1];


nmf1 = Import["nmf0.mx"]
nmf1 == nmf0
```

(* True *)

```
pcit1 = Table[nmf1[[iSet]]["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"], {iSet,Length@nmf1}]


pcit0 == pcit1
```

(* True *)

Comment: One fact to be aware of: "MX files cannot be exchanged between different operating systems or versions of the Wolfram System." [[MX](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html)]

Comment: Good point.  Changing the extension to .m for the Import/Export also works and can be read with a text editor.

Comment: I would consider [WDX](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html) as the platform-independet equivalent to the MX format.

Comment: @rivercfd Thank you. It works well and I can also mix in other strings and results. Is there an obvious class of file types that works? I did try others and failed.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you for pointing WDX out. I will investigate.

Comment: AFAIK you need to use an MMA native format (e.g. .wdx, .m, .mx). that can assign the appropriate expression (Head, contents, etc) to a variable.

Comment: @rivercfd Thanks, I have now learnt about  MMA native formats and that you can use them for anything.